# Mailchimp signup form suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mailchimp

I have a Mailchimp signup form on a client's website which was working fine until this week, I don't know what happened but when I submit a new email address it returns an error which I can't see in the debugger tool.

I don't know if it has anything to do with the code or if Mailchimp made changes to their system but here's the code used for the signup form, I haven't made this plugin so I don't know if anything is missing.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" class="c-mailchimp">
    <input type="text" class="mce-validator" value="" style="display: none;">
    <input type="email" class="with-button mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Votre courriel" required>
    <button type="submit" class="stick-to-input mc-embedded-subscribe">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="mce-responses">
        <div class="c-mailchimp__response mce-error-response" style="display:none">Oups, une erreur est survenue..</div>
        <div class="c-mailchimp__response mce-success-response" style="display:none">Merci de vous être inscrit !</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**custom-mce.php**

```
<?php
/*
   Plugin Name: Agence CC
   Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/agence-cc/
   Version: 1
   Author: Agence CC
   Description: 
   Text Domain: agencecc
   License: GPLv3
  */

add_action( 'wp_ajax_submitMailchimpNewUser', 'submitMailchimpNewUser' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_submitMailchimpNewUser', 'submitMailchimpNewUser' );

function submitMailchimpNewUser() {

    require_once 'includes/mailchimp.php';

    $newUserEmail = $_POST['email'];

    $subscribeResult = syncMailchimp($apiKey, $listId, $newUserEmail);

    echo $subscribeResult;

    die();

}

?>
```

**mailchimp.php**

```
<?php

$apiKey = 'Hidden for security purpose';
$listId = 'Hidden for security purpose';

function syncMailchimp($apiKey, $listId, $email) {

    $memberId = md5(strtolower($email));
    $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);

    $url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listId . '/members/'.$memberId;

    $json = json_encode([
        'email_address' => $email,
        'status' => "subscribed",
    ]);

    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json);

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $curlInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    if($httpCode===200) {
        return 'true';
    } else {
        return 'false';
    }
}
```

**Inside the app.js**

```
var initMailChimp = function() {

    var $submitButton = $('.mc-embedded-subscribe');

    $submitButton.click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var $email = $(this).closest('form').find('.mce-EMAIL');
        var email = $email.val();
        var success = $(this).closest('form').find('.mce-success-response');
        var error = $(this).closest('form').find('.mce-error-response');
        var validator = $(this).closest('form').find('.mce-validator').val();

        if(validator!=='') {

            error.hide();
            success.slideDown(300);
            $email.val('');

        } else {

            $.post(
                ajaxurl, 
                {
                    'action': 'submitMailchimpNewUser',
                    'email': email
                }, 
                function(response){
                    if(response==='true') {
                        error.hide();
                        success.slideDown(300);
                        $email.val('');
                    } else {
                        success.hide();
                        error.slideDown(300);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Is your API key still valid? Try to var_dump($result) in mailchimp.php, it should give you the full response from the curl, which will likely contain an error message from mailchimp.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added var_dump($result) in mailchimp.php but it doesn't output anything when I submit the form.